# Why does this shift insert 1s? C

Tags: c, bit, bit-shift

I am trying to create a 32bit binary with all 0s except srt to end which would be 1s. So if srt is 2 and end is 7 the I would get 00000000 00000000 00000001 11111100. When I do the second shift it gives more 1s instead of zeros, I don't know why. Very knew to C and bit manipulation, if someone could explain I'd be very grateful.

```
int groupOne(int srt, int end){
    int mask =-1;
    int ret;
    ret = 1<<end;
    ret=ret<<srt;

    ret = mask+ret;
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: 2's complement?

Comment: `start` would be a much more informative parameter name than `srt`.

Comment: @Kingsley: I'd agree with the name change, except that the example seems to show 7 1-bits with the least significant of those in position 2 — hence `00000001 11111100` for the number (written to 16 bits instead of 32 bits).  A better name for `srt` might be `len` or `num_bits` or something along those lines, therefore.

Answer (score 2):

From the C Committee draft (N1570) on:

> **6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators**
>   ...
>   Semantics
>   3 The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is
>   that of the promoted left operand. *If the value of the right operand is negative or is
>   greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.*
>
> 4 The result of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. If `E1` has an unsigned type, the value of the result is `E1 × 2E2` (2 power E2), reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. If `E1` has a signed type and nonnegative value, and `E1 × 2E2` (2 power E2) is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.
>
> 5 The result of `E1 >> E2` is `E1` right-shifted `E2` bit positions. If `E1` has an unsigned type
>   or if `E1` has a signed type and a nonnegative value, the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of `E1 / 2E2` (2 power E2). If `E1` has a signed type and a negative value, *the resulting value is implementation-defined.*

Comment: Yes, it's much easier to do all bitwise operations on `unsigned` values.